# 2 expect blocks in Spock?

Tags: spock

I have the following Spock test, which passes:

```java
def "test"() {
  given:
    def name = "John"
  expect:
    name.length() == 4
  when:
    name = name.concat(name)
  then:
    name.length() == 8
}
```

But when I modify the last `then` block and make it an `expect` block...

```java
// previous part same
  expect:
    name.length() == 8
```

I am getting:

```
Groovy-Eclipse: Groovy:'expect' is not allowed here; instead, use one of: [and, then]
```

Is it because multiple `expect` blocks are not allowed in a single test? If so, is this documented anywhere? There is a similar test [here](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#utilities) written with `given - expect - when - then` but it is not clear why a second `expect` was not used, although what is being asserted is same, just being flipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`when-expect` is simply a syntax error with regard to Spock's specification DSL. The compiler message already tells you how to solve your problem. After `when` you need `then` (or `and` first, if you want to structure your `when` block into multiple sections). In contrast, `expect` is a kind of `when-then` contracted into a single block, because both the stimulus and verifying the response in a condition appear together. Block labels and how to use them is documented [here](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_blocks).

Under [Specifications as Documentation](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#specifications_as_documentation), you learn more about why you might want to use `and` and block labels. Under [Invocation Order](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_invocation_order_2) you learn about what you can achieve by using multiple `then` blocks in contrast to `then-and`.

You can use multiple `expect` blocks within one feature, no problem. But you do need to make sure that your `when-then` (if any) is complete, before you can use another `expect`.

For example, this is a valid feature:

```java
  def "my feature"() {
    given: true
    and: true
    and: true

    expect: true

    when: true
    and: true

    then: true
    and: true

    then: true

    expect: true
    and: true

    cleanup: true
  }
```